# How were the synaptic areas identified in the somatic sensation pathways?

Tags: human-anatomy, experimental-design, neuroanatomy

I'm studying the somatic sensation pathways in neuro-anatomy and I was wondering what was the experimental procedure for identifying the number and location of the synapses in these pathways? Additionally, how were they known to not branch anywhere? Did they use dyes or green fluorescent protein? These are the only visualization techniques I know.

Comment: Check out the work of [Denny-Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derek_Denny-Brown) in humans.  I suspect this work that you describe was done much earlier, but you may be able to follow some of the references backwards from him.